# What are the lines of a surface plot called?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am wondering what are the names of the specific names of the lines used when a program such as Matlab or Mathematica plots a surface in 3D. They are lines which are the intersection between planes parallel to the axis and the surface itself.

[image]

As opposed to say contour lines or

[image]

And what are the lines usually presented with sphere?

[image]

Comment: gradient curves?

Comment: Wouldn't the gradient for the center peak, all be pointed towards the center unlike how it is in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "trace." In usage one typically specifies the direction to take the trace, e.g. "This family of curves is generated by taking traces in the $xy$-direction.

Depending on the context, one might also use "gradient curves," "contours," or "level curves/sets." However, these are usually reserved for more specialized circumstances.

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking for. More reference: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/MultiVrbleFcns.aspx